# Using Cordova navigator.notification.alert in Ionic2

Tags: cordova, ionic2, alert, navigator

How to add cordova alert dialog in ionic?

navigator.notification.alert(data.message,data.title,"Ok",this.alertHandler())

navigator.notification throws error.Do I need to declare anything?Am using alert in app.component.ts.Please help

Update...

[I have tried using (window).navigator.plugin too.But getting a syntax error.Please check the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NEiM.png)

Comment: I have declared...But still alert of undefined

Comment: Alert of undefined? So you do get an alert? Please edit your question and add your error

Comment: A hacky way of doing this that **could** work is `window.plugin.nagivator.notification.alert(....)` or `(window).navigator.notification.alert(....)`

Comment: syntax err coming for window.navigator.navigation.alert()

Comment: That wasn't one of the options

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the **[cordova-plugin-dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs)** to your project?

Your parameters are in the wrong order, the sample `alert` from the README is this:

```
function alertDismissed() {
    // do something
}

navigator.notification.alert(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    alertDismissed,         // callback
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Done'                  // buttonName
);
```

> navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title],
>   [buttonName])

Comment: navigator.notification is not detected...That's the problem